# Looking for "network interface" system icon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I was hoping to use a specific icon in an cocoa application I've been working on. The icon is used in the dialog displayed below. For some reason I have always known this icon as the "network interface icon" but I'm sure it has some other name. Since I started looking for the icon I can't think of where I've seen it before, lucky I found the image below after a few google searches. Can anybody help identify the icon, and how I could find where it is stored on the OS?

http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7080/8021xauth.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon belongs to the Internet Connect.app.

Internet Connect.app...

> ... allows the user to activate dial-up connections to the Internet via an ISP or VPN. It also provides a simple way to connect to an AirPort Network.

The Internet Connect.app was discontinued from 10.5 onwards and its functions were incorporated into the Network Preference Pane in System Preferences**

[image: screenshot of Internet Connect icon]

Comment: Just wanted to add that I found the actual icon file in the Instruments bundle under resources. So if anybody with 10.5+ needs the icon, now you know where to look.